# Converter decimal para binário no Scratch

Tags: lógica, scratch

Pq não tá exibindo o resultado na tela? Tentei converter número decimal para binário no Scratch, mas não tá funcionando. Alguém pode ver qual o erro?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

A melhor solução para gerar os dígitos binários, é utilizar uma lista para armazenar os dígitos e um *looping* para reduzir a variável `entradaUsuario` a cada iteração.

A cada iteração do *looping*, o algoritmo extrai o dígito binário através de uma operação de resto da divisão por 2 e armazena esse dígito na lista.

Em seguida, divide `entradaUsuario` por 2 até que ele atingir o valor zero.

Segue o algoritmo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Link para o projeto no site do Scratch: [Decimal para Binário](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/224556532/)

---

Caso você realmente precise obter os dígitos em variáveis separadas, basta executar o algoritmo sem o *looping*, repetindo o código para o número de dígitos binários que você precisar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]